# What's the most useful thing to say/link to when a user doesn't escape inputs in their example? (or other common pitfalls)

Tags: discussion, answers, help

It's not too uncommon to see poor code examples in questions where a user hasn't escaped their user inputs in one way or another.

For Example:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO foo VALUES ($_POST['bar'], $_POST['baz'])");
```

and this question: [Update Mysql column field based on email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850585/update-mysql-column-field-based-on-email-address)

This is often the first thing I notice about a post, and even though most of the time it's not part of the initial problem, I feel it needs to be mentioned - some might argue it's more important than answering the question.

What is the best thing to do in this situation? It's almost like we should have a short url to link to, or an FAQ page with these common pitfalls on.

Comment: @Siva basically it leaves the user open for SQL injection, but they do not know it/understand it - aside from their main question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Right

> *Your approach leaves your code open to SQL injection.  Consider using
> Parameters instead.* 
> -- You 1 hour ago
>
> *Thanks, I'll keep that in mind.* -- Me 1 hour ago

### Wrong

> *Never use this kind of code!  You're going to get haxorzd beyond
> belief.* -- You 1 hour ago
>
> *Thanks, but this is an internal application, and it's never going to
> see the light of day beyond these walls, so I think I'll be all right.* -- Me 1 hour ago
>
> *It doesn't matter.  You're doing it wrong, I'm offended and can't
> answer your question. >.<* -- You 1 hour ago.

Laugh if you want, but this has happened to me before (I've exaggerated only slightly for dramatic effect).

Comment: Dramatic effect has been appreciated as has the overall message. +tick

Comment: In general, I agree. In practice, there are far too many people who don't appreciate the dire consequences of such practices when you leave only mild comments like the first example. Obviously you need to keep a professional tone, but there *are* times when more emphasis might be needed. (Or I might just be a jerk--hard to say for sure.)

Answer (score 6):

Always mention such risks. If you're answering the main question, mention it as an aside (“You need to foo the bar, like this: blah blah. By the way, another problem in your code is that it's vulnerable to an [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection); you should use this instead: <correct code>.”) If you're not answering the main question, write a comment.

Comment: +1 for *always* mention such risks. Even if you elide error-checking-, validation-, etc. specific code for purposes of clarity, *always* mention specifically that it should be included in production code.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on whether the question is "help me fix a bug in this production code" or "here's a simplified example similar to a problem I have."

In the first case, a polite suggestion about sanitizing inputs and security practices is probably acceptable.

In the second case, it's probably irrelevant at best and obnoxious at worst.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know php. So, I don't know what the above code is doing, except that I know it is inserting data in to a table named **foo**. Naming a table **foo** is bad, I guess. ;-)

*This is my take:*

- If I find something that the OP can do better, I usually mention the available alternative solutions so the OP can learn to solve their problem better.
- Keep in mind, that you are answering a question that might potentially help others who may come across a similar problem in future.
- If you find something wrong in OP's approach, point it out so that OP as well as others too can learn from it.
- If possible, provide links that might provide them a good read about the topic. In this case, point them out to links that might show case the down sides of SQL injection and the best practices to avoid that.
- If OP is of the type who is willing to learn, they will pick it up from there. Even if not OP, others who come across the question might learn a thing or two.

Comment: Basically the user is leaving themself open to SQL injection, but they do not know it/understand it - this is aside from their main question

Answer (score 1):

I think mentioning it is certainly worthwhile, but in a way that would not be taken as patronizing by someone who does know better but is trying to illustrate a problem in a clear fashion. Personally, I don't want to see several lines of anti-injection measures when they're not relevant to the problem at hand.

I certainly think it should only be a comment, unless the question specifically refers to increasing the security of the code.