# Regain reputation after fixing answer

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

I recently posted what I believe is a good answer to a question.

I answered the question in its entirety but received a downvote for leaving out some EXTRA information (that the poster hadn't asked about at all).  Granted, it was a valuable piece of information.

Another user commented on it, and I added the extra info to rectify the problem.

However, I still have lost reputation despite having fixed my answer (not too important).
But worse, because of the downvote, my good answer is being overlooked.

Anyway to suggest/ask the downvoter to review the ammendments?

The *question in question* ;| is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333006/insert-large-amount-of-variables-into-table-using-pdo/13333344#13333344):

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When people are talking about leaving out "extra information" and getting a downvote they have normally posted code that is vulnerable to SQL injection (and a quick check on your profile confirmed this). This has been discussed [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119822/ethics-for-sql-insert-queries-vulnerable-to-sql-injection) note the most highly voted answer *not* the accepted one.

There is nothing you can do about the one downvote you received unless the downvoter comes back to your answer and rescinds their vote. What you *can* do is not make the same mistake again. If your code is vulnerable to SQL injection there will always be at least one person who downvotes you. If you don't want this to happen don't post vulnerable code.

Answer (score 3):

If yo get downvoted and the downvoter does not change his/her vote, there is nothing you can do about it.

If your answer is correct and the best one it will get noticed anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is not possible to leave a comment for which the down-voters are notified (for example, one starting with @downvoters), there is no way to notify the users who down-voted you that you updated your answer. It could be nice if down-voters are automatically notified when a post they down-voted is edited, but that is not actually implemented.

If the user who down-voted your answer will see you removed that part, and if the user thinks your answer is better now, then s/he will remove her/his down-vote. Otherwise, your answer will get an up-vote from somebody else. In such case, you still gain reputation (8 point for each up-vote matching a down-vote).