# Is it really important for me to elaborate every answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

A day ago, I answered a question on stackoverflow. The question is linked below and you can see my answer there.

Basically I answered what the OP asked. I gave a short and exact answer by just modifying the code OP provided which fixes his issue. Now, another SO member down voted my answer and commented that the solution you provided is inefficient.

Now, I want to ask that do I have to explain each and every thing in the answer regardless of OP asked for it or not. What I believe is the answer should be point to point that is `What you asked = What you get` philosophy.

Please correct me if my way of thinking is wrong.

[This the question I am referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949944/for-each-loop-php-insert-into-sql-not-inserting-data/21949982#21949982).

Comment: Exactly what discussion are you looking for here? Are you looking for a reason behind the downvote? If that is the case, you're out of luck. A users votes is theirs alone - they are not required to provide reasoning...

Comment: In my opinion,  your thinking is wrong.  People frequently ask the wrong question.  It is our job as the experts to see this, explain how they are asking the wrong question, then answer the question they should have asked. Doing this helps to make both the OP and all future readers better programmers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Yes.

You are not just answering for the questioner; you're answering for the thousands of people who're going to view that page afterwards. You need to provide a decent explanation in every answer; you need to explain:

- What was wrong with the OPs code/approach
- What the correct answer would be
- Why your answer is the correct one.
- Whether there's a better approach that the OP should be using.

If you just answer with code, and no explanation, I (and others) will not upvote you. If you answer without using best practice but just fix a typo you will be downvoted as you've encouraged thousands of people to do something that they really shouldn't.

See also: [Ethics for SQL insert queries vulnerable to SQL injection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119822/ethics-for-sql-insert-queries-vulnerable-to-sql-injection)

Comment: That helped alot and also settled my anger down. Thanks for reply I will keep this in mind next time.