# Handling correct answers with insecure code

Tags: discussion, question-quality, answer-quality

I often read and answer to questions on cryptography usage in Java. I noticed that a large number of questions contain totally insecure code. Also answers often answer the questions but do not correct the code part with causes the security threat.

Hence, users who copy code from SO into their programs include that security threat into that program - which is from my perspective a bad situation.

On the other had if I create I write an answer with an hint what is wrong with the question and the answer it is getting deleted by community moderators like "Andrew Barber".

How to handle that situation? Placing a comment on a question or an answer is bad because it is not well visible and 600 characters are way to less to explain the problem.

I don't want to write the third or forth answer just for explaining why that code is totally insecure and bad. I just want to point out the problem. How to to that with an minimum effort in a community accepted way?

Comment: You don't just point out the problem in an answer. That you do in a comment. You write an entirely new answer that is correct and safe, if you feel that's necessary. It has to be self-contained, and not a "reply" to something else. As as for *"users who copy code from SO into their programs include that security threat into that program "* ... if they are really that careless, I'm not sure we should worry too much about them.

Comment: Highly related: [Ethics for SQL insert queries vulnerable to SQL injection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119822/ethics-for-sql-insert-queries-vulnerable-to-sql-injection)

Comment: You could write a *good* question that asks about how to avoid writing insecure code, and write a good answer yourself. Subsequently, when you see a poor answer, you could link to your question via a comment.

Comment: @AdrianHHH That does not work because if the user does search for different terms the question is never found. I think it has to something that is present right in the question/answer the best on top of it.

Comment: @Bart I am sorry but that solution does not work for me. I don't want to spend my time a question that has been already answered. If I encounters such a question I want to precisely point out the problem hence comments are useless. BTW: We are talking about hundreds of posts...

Comment: A question that has already been answered? How so? By your own account, even if it has been answered, it has been answered poorly and potentially dangerously. So where's the problem in providing a good and proper answer. I'm not telling you to do so for hundreds of posts out there, but the best solution to bad answers is downvoting them, and providing an alternative good answer.

Comment: @Robert I believe that commenting on other's answers is way to highlight problems thererin. My suggestion was that you write a good Q&A and then add comments to other people's poor answers with a link to your Q&A, you could add words such as "there are [security] problems with this answer, see point 42 of the answer to [link to your Q&A]". I was not expecting people writing poor answers to search for your posts.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest simply leaving a comment on the answer that possibly hints or points to the part of the answer that has the issue in it. Nothing rude, just something that points out either a poor implementation or insecure section of code.

The folks the MySQL and PHP threads do this all the time when users post questions with code that has deprecated mysql_* functions in it. THe better comments will actually link to a question/answer explaining WHY they should move away from these old functions - such as this one: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: I'd also consider downvoting the post.

Comment: @JanDvorak You should spend a little time in the PHP Queue hehe. I almost want to upvote questions and answers that are spelt correctly and coherent as they are so refreshing :)